# Search a Specific Word or a Sentence on a Web Page (https) using php

Tags: php

What would be the right php code to search for a specific word in a specific https URL and if it exists, return a message?

For example... 
URL: https://www.example.com/ ,
Search for word: "illustrative" ,
Return: "Found"

I've seen some questions about this, but couldn't find the exact answer to my question, I'd be glad if anyone could help.

Thx

Comment: As @Berto99 mentions there is the built-in `strpos()` function. However you will have to get the page contents too which you could do thru the built-in function `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a good starting point:

```
function page_contains($link, $word){
      return strpos(file_get_contents($link), $word) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
}
page_contains('https://www.example.com/', 'illustrative');
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a word inside HTML is not as trivial as a needle-haystack search, unfortunately. You have to account for the fact that the HTML itself may contain your search word/phrase thus providing a false positive.

For example, consider the following HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="illustrative productions">
        <script>
            var illustrative = true;
        </script>
        <style>
            .illustrative {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="illustrative">Hello World</h1>
        <p>Your search word never appears here.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If we did a simple `strpos()` search on this document we'd get a false positive even though the word we're searching for would never actually show up on the rendered page in a browser.

So the first problem is that we'd have to parse the HTML document first and extract only the **text nodes** in the document to search. This can be achieved simply with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) like so...

```
function findWord(String $url, String $searchWord): Bool {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $htmlContent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

    $text = $htmlContent->textContent;

    return strpos($text, $searchWord) !== false;
}

// First let's start with a URL we know the word exists
$url = "https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illustrative";

// Gives us "Found"
if (findWord($url, "illustrative")) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}

// Now let's try a URL we know the word doesn't exist
$url = "https://php.net/";

// Gives us "Not Found"
if (findWord($url, "illustrative")) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Keep in mind this solution will also find partial matches, so if you were searching for words like "*pan*" and the word "*pancake*" is found inside the document it will still trigger. This also doesn't account for things like [lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) where you search for the root of a word such that you can find all of its inflections; such as when you search for the word "*illustrative*" the search also returns results for "*illustration*", "*illustrative*", and "*illustrate*" with all of its pluralization. This is a technique common in search engines, for example, because of the fact that search words and phrases may appear in a document in many inflected forms. Indexing all possible inflections may be too costly and storing a dictionary of all such inflections would also be too costly. Thus words are stemmed or lemmatized to perform more accurate searches. Finally, this particular search is case-sensitive so if you intend on case-insensitive search you should use the case-insensitive form `stripos()` instead of `strpos()`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for very detailed explanation. I ran it and both give Not Found. So the result is "Not FoundNot Found"

Comment: Then the issue is likely with your connection to the Internet. Make sure you check your error log or turn on dipslay_errors. Most likely the call to `file_get_contents()` failed resulting in no document to find the word. I assure you the code works exactly as expected: https://paiza.io/projects/KUOI-523g6njjcCoDU7y4Q

Comment: To prove this I've replaced the call of `file_get_contents()` and directly injected the HTML into the function: https://3v4l.org/NpugV As you can see it works exactly as expected.